# How to do models compare of two different catia part minding there is no direct API to do so..?

Tags: automation, catia

How to do models compare of two different catia part minding there is no direct API to do so.. ?

Answer (score 0):

With DMU Space Analysis workbench you can visually compare models. At the moment I can't access that license, but you can try recording a macro while executing the Compare Products feature to understand if some methods are exposed to scripting